# Do Not Understand fmap of Function and Value in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am confused about the result of this expression:

```
fmap (*) 3
```

Which produces type:

```
fmap (*) 3 :: (Functor f, Num a, Num (f a)) => f (a -> a)
```

What I was expecting is that the result would be the same as doing:

```
(*) 3
```

Which produces a 1-parameter function:

```
Prelude> (*) 3 $ 10
30
```

I was expecting that `fmap` would apply `3` to `(*)` producing `(*3)`, but the following produces an error:

```
Prelude> (fmap (*) 3) 10

<interactive>:201:1:
    Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (a -> a)
    (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    When checking that `it' has the inferred type
      it :: forall a a1. (Num a, Num a1, Num (a1 -> a)) => a -> a
```

What type of parameter is the result of `(fmap (*) 3)` expecting?

Comment: Why do you expect that `fmap (*) 3` should be exactly the same as `(*) 3`? The `fmap` function is clearly making some kind of a difference, and i don't imagine you expect that, say, `filter (*) 3` would be the same.

Comment: You're confusing mapping with application. `fmap` is a generalized `map` function, not at all like `($)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key is here:

```
fmap (*) 3 :: (Functor f, Num a, Num (f a)) => f (a -> a)
                                 ^^^^^^^^^
```

In Haskell numeric literals are overloaded, so `3` could have any type `b` as long as `b` has a `Num` instance.

The compiler goes through the following analysis:

1. 3 has some type `b` with constraint `Num b`
2. `fmap` has type `Functor f => (a -> c) -> f a -> f c`
3. So `*` has type `a -> c` and 3 has type `f a`
4. `*` has type `Num a => a -> a -> a` so `c` = `a -> a`, and `a` has constraint `Num a`
5. `b` = `f a` from (1) and (2)

Gathering up all of the constraints and equivalences:

```
fmap (*) 3 :: ( Functor f,       -- by (2)
                Num a,           -- by (4)
                Num (f a)        -- by (1) and (5)
              ) => f ( a -> a )  -- by (2) and c = a -> a
```

Update:

You asked for an example where `fmap (*) 3` makes sense. What is problematic here is that `(*)` has arity 2 and `fmap` is usually used with a function of a single argument (arity 1). For instance:

```
fmap (+1) (Just 3)  = Just 4
fmap (+1) Nothing   = Nothing
fmap (*6) [1,2,3]   = [6,12,18]
fmap words getLine  = do x <- getLine; return (words x)
```

Note: `(+1)` is just the "add 1" function, e.g. `\x -> x+1`, and `(*6)` is just the multiply by 6 function, e.g. `\x -> x*6`.

So fmapping `(*) :: Int -> Int -> Int` is somewhat unusual. Of course, we  can interpret the type of `(*)` to be `Int -> (Int -> Int)` which gives it arity 1, but then dealing with functors of functions is getting into a level of abstraction that we don't normally deal with.

Comment: Can you give an example of `(fmap (*) 3) X` where `X` is a value that does not cause the expression to end in error?

Comment: @kurzweil4 It should be possible to do that, but why do you expect the result of `fmap (*) 3` to be a function? It has type `f (a -> a)`, which is not necessarily a function type. E.g., `f` could be `[]`, making `fmap (*) 3` a list of functions, not a function.

Comment: I do not know what to expect at all from the output, so seeing an example of how to use the output would help me to grasp the problem.

Comment: You can write a `Num` instance for lists, like `instance Num a => [a] where fromInteger x = [fromInteger x]`, then `fmap (*) 3` would be `fmap (*) [3]`, which is `[(*) 3]`.

Comment: @kurzweil4 - I added some more to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the update! So the answer then is that the output of `fmap (*) 3` is a functor of function of `a ->a`?

Comment: It's valuable to note that any for any `Applicative f` instance there is a generic way of writing a `Num a => Num (f a)` instance. Operations like `fmap (*)` are completely normal with `Applicative` instances—in the the common applicative `f <$> a <*> b` idiom, `<$>` is just a synonym for `fmap`.